# Instagram URL tracking parameters

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

For example, if you get a link to your profile in the Instagram app, you can use the with the parameter igshid. What does this mean?

From what I've found, I believe it's a tracking parameter, but should I remove this parameter when embedding it in the web site?

Please let me know if you have any documentation or sites on this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely used to track the user's account in which the embed or link was generated from. There is no official documentation or information on it, nor does there appear to be any benefit to using it.

Since it's an optional parameter, you're best off eliminating it if you do not want to be tracked.